# No X11 Display variable set error only when running through ant

Tags: java, ant, awt, testng, headless

I am running java testng tests on an headless server. I am getting below error only when I am using the ant xml file for running. When I an running it through java `org.testng.TestNG` command everything is working perfectly. Please let me know what can be done to run it through ant.
I have set `DISPLAY` variable: `DISPLAY=:99`
I am using `xvfb` as a virtual display and starting it before running ant.

Error through ant is

```
java.awt.HeadlessException: 
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
    at sun.java2d.HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.getDefaultScreenDevice(HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.java:77)
```

Comment: How did you set the DISPLAY?  The error says it is not the case. You may need to export the variable correctly.

Comment: I used export DISPLAY=:99 to set the DISPLAY variable

Comment: @ user2473303 : It is getting reset, somehow

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace suggests that you're trying to get the default screen `GraphicsDevice` in headless mode.

The documentation says that [getDefaultScreenDevice](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#getDefaultScreenDevice%28%29) throws `HeadlessException - if isHeadless() returns true`.